# Why does DateFormat#format accept int parameter?

Tags: java

I have this class:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Test  {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");


        String h = df.format(1);
        System.out.println(h);//output:
    }
}
```

It compiles without problems with openjdk 7.

AFAIK there's no DateFormat#format(int).

Is there any implicit cast that converts 1 to Date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's inherited from [`Format#format(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Format.html#format%28java.lang.Object%29) and the `int` is being [autoboxed](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) to [`Integer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html). The value is by the way interpreted as epoch time.

Comment: ah, ok. didn't notice the inheritance.

Comment: It's below the method summary in [the `SimpleDateFormat` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), in the section titled "Methods inherited from class java.text.Format".

Comment: yeah yeah, now i see it. stupid me. got to get some coffee :)

Answer (score 0):

DateFormat inherits from class Format the method format(Object) (see [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Format.html#format%28java.lang.Object%29)). And int can implicitly be converted to Object by autoboxing it into a java.lang.Integer.